# Two programs links to dynamic linked library

Tags: c, dynamic, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I'm still a noob in C, so I have a question about linking.
We have two programs "A" and "B", which links to the dynamic linked library "C".

Now we start program "A" and "B".

What happened now to "C". Will it be loaded once for both programs, or two times for every program?

And what is, when program B is a Python program, which make use of the foreign function interface?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the operating system, but for e.g. Linux or Windows the shared library will only be loaded once, but it will be *mapped* twice. Each process using the shared library will have the library mapped, but those mappings all lead to the same single loaded library.

The mapping is done on a per-process basis, it doesn't really matter what the process does or is (if it's a program you made, a Python interpreter, or something completely different).

Comment: What do you mean by mapped?

Comment: @clausismus On modern multi-user multi-tasking operating systems, all processes have their own memory map, it's called [*virtual memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). *Mapping* is what one does to add something to the process memory map. This memory-mapping can lead to a shared library having different *virtual addresses* in two different processes.

Comment: Both programs "A" and "B" linked to once loaded library "C". If the library "C" has a static char buffer, and a function to return a pointer from the buffer, then both programs should get the same buffer pointer?

Comment: @clausismus Both processes gets a pointer to the same buffer, but the pointer value (the address) in processes A and B may be different, because of virtual memory.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly: When "A" change the values of the buffer, "B" can obtain the changed values? If "C" is static linked library, and "A" and "B" links to it, then there should be two buffers. Correct?

Comment: @clausismus Yes, a static library is really nothing more than a collection of object files, and are linked only to the specific output file which means the data segments is for that process only.

Answer (score 0):

Searching google for `Dynamic linking C` gave me the following result (Shared libraries are dynamically loaded)

Shared libraries are loaded into memory by programs when they start. When a shared library is loaded properly, all programs that start later automatically use the already loaded shared library.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Windows, only the DLL (dynamic link library) code is shared between processes. Each process has it's own virtual memory address space, including the data used by a DLL. This means that a DLL normally can't have a static buffer that is shared between processes. The process or DLL code can set up shared memory, and that shared memory can be shared between processes.

MSDN articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681914(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682594(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/windows/desktop/ms686958(v=vs.85).aspx